# Configure IPSec so the user identity is passed to iptables rule

Tags: iptables, passwd, ipsec

Hi I'm pretty new to this so you'll have to be very explicit.

I set up IPSec on CentOS so that I can VPN. User identities are stored in the `/etc/ppp/chap-secrets`, mainly because that's how things work in the installation script I used.

Now I want to write some rules to block certain sites based on the user. I tried:

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING  -s badsite.com -m owner --uid-owner 100 -i eth0 -p tcp -s --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-destination http://myserver.com/blockedsitewarning
```

where 100 is my child's unix account ID. But this won't work because of course the `chap-secrets` account is completely separate from the `passwd` account.

How would I configure IPSec and/or iptables so that they will use the same authentication system and user identity? Please post actual configuration files rather than just abstract concepts or links to man pages. Thanks!!!

Comment: Why don't you assign a fixed ip address to each VPN user, and then apply different firewall rules according to the source ip address? That's a more common approach and shoudn't be too hard to implement.

Comment: IPSec can use [PAM](https://raymii.org/s/tutorials/IPSEC_L2TP_vpn_on_CentOS_-_Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux_or_Scientific_-_Linux_6.html), but I doubt you can accomplish what you intend to on the iptables side.

Comment: I can't say that there isn't a kernel module to add this, but considering that kernel firewall rules run in a very performance-sensitive area of the kernel there probably isn't a way to do dynamic lookups on the username of a VPN connection.  I think simlev has the right idea with assigning a distinct IP addr to each user, then generating firewall rules based on those.  Your UID method only works by looking at the process generating the packet, which can't be known for VPN.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't very well do this, and it probably wouldn't work anyway.

The reason why "--to-destination http://myserver.com/blockedsitewarning" won't work is that it is a URL and not a site, and `iptables` knows nothing about URLs; it works at the level of TCP/IP addresses and ports. The best you could do is redirect to "myserver.com".

Also, several sites (for example google.com, but also Microsoft and some heavy-traffic porn sites) have several IP addresses or are reached through a so-called "CDN" (Content Delivery Netework). When you tell iptables to block google.com, `iptables` will resolve **in that instant** the address of google.com and use that number henceforth. So you'll have blocked the address that the DNS system returned for google.com *in that particular instant for that one query*, and it's very likely that some time later, the same query will return a *different* address, one that the rule just given won't cover.

What you need to do to block **sites** is something quite different:

- install a **transparent proxy** such as Squid, which knows all about hosts and URLs, using `iptables` to redirect ports 80 and 443 to the local host (an old tutorial may be found [here](https://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/linux-setup-transparent-proxy-squid-howto.html) but Google is your friend). Now, all traffic will be directed by `iptables` through `squid`.
- set up a Squid *deny list* - you can use [Squidguard](http://www.squidguard.org/) but I know there are also organization publishing "child blacklists".
- tell Squid to map all denied accesses to either an error page, or a local site on your machine.